# Как изменить цвет чекбоксов Android ListView (simple_list_item_single_choice)?

Tags: android, listview, style, color

Использую в приложении ListView с возможностью выбора одного элемента (simple_list_item_single_choice) . Как можно поменять цвет чекбоксов для выбора элементов? Хотелось бы, чтобы этот кружок был белым и пустым внутри, если элемент не выбран, и белым внутри, если элемент выбран. Писать кастомный список слишком долго, интуитивно догадываюсь, что это делается гораздо проще.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/paytypeslist"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/doublemenutopandbottompaddings"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:divider="#00000000"
android:dividerHeight="@dimen/doublemenuhalftbpaddings"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:scrollX="0px"
android:scrollY="0px"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView) v;

            textview.setCheckMarkTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(PayActivity.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorwhite)));

            textview.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorwhite));

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы изменить цвет чекбокса вам нужно прописать ему отдельный цвет и его стиль в файл в папке /drawable. Например можно сделать такой чекбокс:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed_holo_light" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
<item android:state_activated="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light" />
```

и дальше этот файлик подключаете к вашему чекбоксу:

```
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
```

либо вы можете это сделать программно:

```
ваш_чекбокс.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {

         if ( isChecked )
        {



        }
        else
         {

        }

    }
});
```

если что-то не получится, то пишите и попытаюсь помочь. Удачи :)

Comment: Да, я примерно представляю, как это делается. Только не знаю, как получить доступ к самому элементу с рисунком внутри ListView. Знаю, что это каким-то образом можно сделать в переопределенном методе public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). Вот и пытаюсь найти, как именно.

Comment: а вы не может получить доступ к чекбоксу через xml?

Comment: Проблема решена парой строк, как я и хотел. Единственная проблема - работает только начиная с api 21. Пойду искать что-то подобное для api 15+

Comment: я бы на вашем месте сделал все через recyclerview, немного больше времени потратите, но потом будет довольно кастомизируемый список)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый